# DataGridView Bug? Cell Style InEdit Doesn't Update

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I currently have a DataGridView which depending on certain row states (which I have defined as "new", "modified", "to be removed" & "normal") I Style rows within my grid with code like this:

```
'Modified
 row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(row.DataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
 row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon
 row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Empty
```

I hook on to various events to accomplish this - and they fire when I expect them.

My issue is that I am using My `DataGridView` in the `EditMode` of `EditOnEnter`.  I'm running into an issue that whichever cell is selected (& therefor in edit mode) is not being updated immediately by my Style change code.  That is until I leave the selected cell for another one.

Here is a couple screen-shots which show's the life-cycle of this issue:

### Before editing anything

[image: Before Editing]

### After modifying a cell

[image]

### After tabbing to another cell

[image]

My Desired result would be transitioning from the first image - directly to the last image (Without having to "tab" out of the cell I'm editing.)  Is there something I can do to accomplish this?

Thanks.

P.S. I'm normally code in C# so I can accept the answer in either language (this project just so happens to be in vb.net v2.0)

Comment: have you tried `CellBeginEdit` event?

Comment: @Bolu Currently I use `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` as I want to mark the row as "modified" as soon as it is modified.  `CellBeginEdit` Oddly appears to fire only when I leave the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but I was searching for awhile to find an answer to this, so I figure it might help someone in the future:

I was able to solve this by attaching to the 'CellFormatting' event, to 'unselect' the cell when the format has been changed.

```
this.DataGridView.CellFormatting += 
    (s, e) => { this.DateGridView.ClearSelection(); }
```